# sql query for product taging to get product having 3 specific tag

Tags: mysql, tags, product

I have database design having 3 table as below:

```
products
pid pname pprice

tags 
tag_id tag_name

products_tag ==> Unique(pid,tag_id)
pid tag_id
65   1
65   3
66   2
88   2
88   4
88   3
```

i have requirement to get all pid which have tagid = 2 and 3 and 4. So result in this case is 88(pid). what will be the sql query for this problem statement?

Answer (score 1):

```
select pid
from products_tag 
where tagid in (2,3,4)
group by pid
having count(tagid) = 3
```

Comment: You dont need `DISTINCT` because `Unique(pid,tag_id)`

Answer (score 0):

use conditional `COUNT`

```
 SELECT PID, COUNT(CASE WHEN tag_id IN (2,3,4) THEN 1 END) as total
 FROM products_tag 
 GROUP BY PID
 HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN tag_id IN (2,3,4) THEN 1 END) = 3
```